# Regex that matches a string that ends with the same sequence as it begins

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string that contains a number of unique sequences that always start and end with an underscore. I am looking for a regex that returns the part of the string between these sequences. I tried to make a capture group for everything between the first two underscores, then there are some characters in between and at the end, i try to match the first capture group. But it does not match anything:

```
std::string s = "somerandomstuff_UNIQUESEQUENCE_somemorethings_UNIQUESEQUENCE_morewords"
std::regex seq("_(.*)_.*_$1_", std::regex_constants::extended);
std::smatch m{};
std::regex_search(s, m, seq);
```

The problem is that I do not know what the sequences are, i only know that they start and end with an underscore (otherwise this would be fairly easy to solve...). Does somebody know a regex for this?

Comment: I don't know the quirks of C++11 std::regex, so I'm not sure this will work, but try `"(_[^_]+_)(.*?)\\1"`.  If it works, `somemorethings` will be match group 2.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.*` is greedy - so it matches `UNIQUESEQUENCE_somemorethings_UNIQUESEQUENCE`, and then the whole regex fails to match.

The solution is actually quite simple.  You know that UNIQUESEQUENCE ends at the first _, so don't match it.  Use a regex of:

```
_([^_]*)_.*_$1_
```